# Using same modal to Add/Edit in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new using AngularJS.

Im making a basic project where I have a CRUD of countries.

The code works well but I have one problem, I want to use the same modal to Add or edit a country, the problem is when I edit a country how I am using ng-model my row with the selected country be edited while I write in the modal, but i only want that when i write only watch the changes in the modal and when I click in the update button I want that my table be update.

So what I have now is that, I can edit a country but when I change it in the modal i can watch the changes in the table meanwhile I am writing and I want that only happens when I click updated.

Here is my code:

```
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Country list</h2>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCountryModal">
  Add country
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="refresh()">
  Refresh list
</button>
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" ng-init='refresh()'>
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Country Name</th>
                <th scope="col">Population</th>
                <th scope="col">Acciones</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
                <td>{{country.countryName}}</td>
                <td>{{country.population}}</td>
                <td>
                    <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addCountryModal" ng-click="selectedCountry(country)" ng-init="isEdit=true">Edit</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="button"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteCountryModal" ng-click="selectedCountry(country)">Delete</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal Add/Edit-->
<div class="modal fade" id="addCountryModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addCountryModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="addCountryModalLabel">Add country</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="countryname">Country Name</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="countryname" ng-model="country.countryName" placeholder="Enter country name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="population">Population</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pupulation" ng-model="country.population"  placeholder="Number of population">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="add()" data-dismiss="modal">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my controller:

```
'use strict';

app.controller('CountryController', ['$scope', 'CountryFactory', '$location', function ($scope, CountryFactory, $location) {

    $scope.country = {};
    $scope.countries = [];
    $scope.isEdit = false;

    $scope.refresh = function () {

        CountryFactory.getCountries().then(function (data) {
            $scope.countries = data.data;
        })
    }

    $scope.add = function () {
        if(!$scope.isEdit){
            CountryFactory.addCountry($scope.country).then(function (data) {
                $scope.countries.push(data.data);
                $scope.country = {};
            })
        }
        else{
            console.log("Countru");
            $scope.isEdit = false;
            CountryFactory.updateCountry($scope.country).then(function (data) {
                $scope.countries.push(data.data);
                $scope.country = {};
            })
        }

    }
    $scope.edit = function (country) {
        $scope.isEdit = true;
        $scope.country = country;
    }

    $scope.delete = function () {
        CountryFactory.deleteCountry($scope.country.id).then(function (data) {
            $scope.countries = $scope.countries.filter(function (item) { return item.id != $scope.country.id })
$scope.country = {};
        })


    }

    $scope.selectedCountry = function (country){
        $scope.country = country;
    }


}]);
```

[Jsfiddle - Country crud](https://jsfiddle.net/0wb7nyf8/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the updates as you type in the edit modal because the edit modal is set to the table's object; they're the same object. Solution? Pass a copy of the object to your edit modal.

```
$scope.selectedCountry = function (country){
  $scope.country = angular.copy(country);
}
```